# Macro for Multiple links

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping, html-tableextract

How do I loop/run the code According to a list in .txt file, until the list is ends ??

How do I loop/run the code According to a list in .txt file, until the list is ends ??

```
Sub FundData()

Dim TikerName As String

    TikerName = 'check & execute the names in list one after one in .txt file until it ends up

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://example.com/index.php?name=" & TikerName, Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        '.CommandType = 0
        .Name = "name=" & TikerName
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = """company"""
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.Name = TikerName
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ThisWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: "ends up ??"  huh?

Comment: There are about 300+ string in 300+ raw,
mean last (row) string of the txt file, like TikerName.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a structure something like this:

```
Sub FundData()

    Dim TikerName As String

    Open "C:\somepath\sometextfile.txt" For Input As #1
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, TikerName

        ' your main code goes here

    Loop
    Close #1
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: showing not responding :(
300+ link access simultaneously from excel in same site, should it be ok??

Comment: @user176705 - I'm not sure I understand your comment.  I can only guess that you mean that your question wasn't meant to be "How do I loop/run the code According to a list in .txt file, until the list is ends up??" but "How do I get sufficient resources so that Excel can perform 300 queries simultaneously".  If so, I suggest you create a new question as that one is wildly different to what you asked.

Comment: Thanks for your nice understanding my friend. I will make a new question soon.